# In moss 2010 after set my customer masterpage to whole web application , master gallery occurs error when upload a file

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

I have developed my own mater page and made it to all the web application,but recently i found when i upload a new masterpage and click save, the page will occurs error:

**Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check.EDocument&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence 
    Request path: /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx**

Anybody know why is it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your customer master page in both definitions in your sharepoint settings? If so, you should only set the first option (site master page) and leave the system master page to the default.master(or v4.master if sp 2010). You are most likely missing a required control in your custom master page.